# .htaccess: How to how a page from a different subomain, without redirect?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain for my short urls, eg: l.example.com/abc123

And I want all the requests for that subdomain, to be mapped to another subdomain, eg: my-app.example.com/short-urls/abc123.

I tried with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^l\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-app.example.com/short-urls/$1 [L]
```

But it makes a redirect.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `P` (proxy) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-app.example.com/short-urls/$1 [L,P]
```

(You also have to enable mod_proxy and allow reverse proxying for this site.)

See RewriteRule docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

---

An other solution would be to alias your short domain to the same vhost are your primary domain:

```
ServerAlias short.domain
```

Answer (score 0):

you absolutely can't, in this situation you should use mod_proxy for reverse proxy.